# Prevent xparse from stripping braces?

Tags: xparse

So I'm trying to implement a `COOL`-style `\Sum` macro which is supposed to support the following syntax:

```
\Sum{\ldots}  % -> \sum \ldots
\Sum[i]{\ldots}  % -> \sum_{i} \ldots
\Sum[i \in I]{\ldots}  % -> \sum_{i \in I} \ldots
\Sum[i, 0, N]{\ldots}  % -> \sum_{i=0}^{N} \ldots
\Sum[{i,j}, 0, N]{\ldots}  % -> \sum_{i,j=0}^{N} \ldots
\Sum[{i,j,k}]{\ldots}  % -> \sum_{i,j,k} \ldots
```

The important bit is that I would like braces to protect commas in the first argument. The actual implementation is in `expl3` with the user interface using `xparse`. Unfortunately, `xparse` appears to always strip braces inside arguments if they surround the whole argument such that this protection will not work in all cases, no matter what my internal code does. Looking at the docs, I couldn't find a way to prevent this.

I tried macros signatures of the forms

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \Sum { s >{ \SplitArgument{2}{,} } o m }
  { ... }
\DeclareDocumentCommand \Sum { s o m }
  { ... }
```

Am I missing something here, is there a (undocumented) way to make xparse not strip such braces short of circumventing xparse and implementing the interface manually (maybe using argument processors?)? If not, would this warrant a bug report/feature request at the latex github?

Comment: Not a solution: You could input `\Sum[{{i,j,k}}]{\ldots}`.

Comment: Why not simply using `;` as delimiter? You would need no braces.

Comment: Using `;` would likely work for my usecases, I don't think I've ever used a semicolon in sum limits. Still, wrapping the argument in braces was the first and obvious (to me) thing I tried to protect arguments that contain the delimiter, and I was surprised that this didn't work. Maybe I'll go for ';' plus the workaround from the other answers (even though that might be overkill)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trick this by inserting another token after the opening bracket if there is one (proof of concept like answer). Replace `\Wisperwind_Sum_original_code:nnn` with your original code to typeset the sum (including the handling of the optional star with `\IfBooleanTF`).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_Wisperwind_clist
\NewDocumentCommand \Sum { s t[ }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF { #2 }
      { \Sum_two { #1 } [ \use_none:n {} }
      { \Sum_two { #1 } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \Sum_two { m O{ \use_none:n {} } m }
  {
    \Wisperwind_Sum_original_code:non { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \Wisperwind_Sum_original_code:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \sum
    \clist_set:Nn \l_Wisperwind_clist { #2 }
    \int_case:nn { \clist_count:N \l_Wisperwind_clist }
      {
        { 1 } { \sb { \clist_item:Nn \l_Wisperwind_clist { \c_one_int } } }
        { 2 }
          {
            \sb { \clist_item:Nn \l_Wisperwind_clist { \c_one_int } }
            \sp { \clist_item:Nn \l_Wisperwind_clist { 2 } }
          }
        { 3 }
          {
            \sb
              {
                \clist_item:Nn \l_Wisperwind_clist { \c_one_int }
                =
                \clist_item:Nn \l_Wisperwind_clist { 2 }
              }
            \sp { \clist_item:Nn \l_Wisperwind_clist { 3 } }
          }
      }
    #3
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \Wisperwind_Sum_original_code:nnn { non }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\Sum{\ldots}$  % -> \sum \ldots
$\Sum[i]{\ldots}$  % -> \sum_{i} \ldots
$\Sum[i \in I]{\ldots}$  % -> \sum_{i \in I} \ldots
$\Sum[i, 0, N]{\ldots}$  % -> \sum_{i=0}^{N} \ldots
$\Sum[{i,j}, 0, N]{\ldots}$  % -> \sum_{i,j=0}^{N} \ldots
$\Sum[{i,j,k}]{\ldots}$  % -> \sum_{i,j,k} \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion (although this is pretty much the 'hack' I had hoped to avoid)! The solution I had in mind would have been closer to @steven-b-segletes answer, but your code preserves the advanced parsing of nested optional arguments that xparse offers.

Answer (score 4):

Here using LaTeX2e (see below for Plain TeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Sum{\@ifnextchar[{\Sumaux[\@gobble}{\sum}}
\makeatother
\def\Sumaux[#1]#2{
  \sum
  \setsepchar{,}
  \readlist\sumargs{#1}
  \ifnum\listlen\sumargs[]>1\relax
    _{\sumargs[1]=\sumargs[2]}
    \ifnum\listlen\sumargs[]>2\relax^\sumargs[3]\fi
  \else
    _{\sumargs[1]}
  \fi
  #2
}
\begin{document}
\[\Sum{\ldots}  \]% -> \sum \ldots
\[\Sum[i]{\ldots}  \]% -> \sum_{i} \ldots
\[\Sum[i \in I]{\ldots}  \]% -> \sum_{i \in I} \ldots
\[\Sum[i, 0, N]{\ldots}  \]% -> \sum_{i=0}^{N} \ldots
\[\Sum[{i,j}, 0, N]{\ldots}  \]% -> \sum_{i,j=0}^{N} \ldots
\[\Sum[{i,j,k}]{\ldots}  \]% -> \sum_{i,j,k} \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

This approach can also be implemented in Plain TeX:

```
\input listofitems
\def\gobble#1{}
\def\Sum{\futurelet\next\doSum}
\def\doSum{\ifx[\next%
  \expandafter\Sumaux\expandafter[\expandafter\gobble\else\sum\fi}
\def\Sumaux[#1]#2{
  \sum
  \setsepchar{,}
  \readlist\sumargs{#1}
  \ifnum\listlen\sumargs[]>1\relax
    _{\sumargs[1]=\sumargs[2]}
    \ifnum\listlen\sumargs[]>2\relax^\sumargs[3]\fi
  \else
    _{\sumargs[1]}
  \fi
  #2
}
$$\Sum{\dots}  $$% -> \sum \ldots
$$\Sum[i]{\ldots}  $$% -> \sum_{i} \ldots
$$\Sum[i \in I]{\ldots}  $$% -> \sum_{i \in I} \ldots
$$\Sum[i, 0, N]{\ldots}  $$% -> \sum_{i=0}^{N} \ldots
$$\Sum[{i,j}, 0, N]{\ldots}  $$% -> \sum_{i,j=0}^{N} \ldots
$$\Sum[{i,j,k}]{\ldots}  $$% -> \sum_{i,j,k} \ldots
\bye
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm writing this using expl3 + xparse, though (obviously I could translate your code to expl3) and for the reason mentioned in another comment will likely prefer @Skillmon 's suggestion

Answer (score 3):

The brace stripping is quite deliberate as `\newcommand`-generated commands requires braces for the case

```
\foo[{]}]{bar}
```

whereas `xparse`-generated  ones do not. Without brace stripping,

```
\foo[{bar}]
```

and

```
\foo[bar]
```

could be treated differently.

In your case, you have a comma list with one entry. The obvious solution is to provide a second, empty, entry

```
\Sum[{i,j},]{\ldots}
```

as this is a no-op.

Comment: I actually find this behavior unexpected AND annoying.  I would prefer `\foo[{bar}]` and `\foo[bar]` to be (potentially) treated differently.  But I also see the need, as in the initial case you present, to embrace the bracket.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I guess the reason is as (almost) always of historical nature. Since optional arguments created with `\newcommand` behave this way (as well as those created with `\def\foo[#1]`) it is the expected behaviour for optional arguments, because it always was this way.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes As we are not changing the catcode of `[`/`]`, the only way to have a TeX `<balanced text>` argument as an optional argument is to use a brace pair. Thus when the optional argument is _exactly_ one balanced text we strip braces. It's the only way to handle stuff 'reasonably'.

Comment: @JosephWright I think I don't really understand what exactly wouldn't work without stripping braces. Wrt the first example, I guess you meant to say `\foo[\bar[baz]]{test}` does not require braces if defined through xparse, because `\foo[{]}]{bar}` does. Is the reason mostly historical in order to match `\newcommand` as @skillmon suggests? For most macros, I would expect additional braces not being stripped to not be an issue, thus this was also rather unexpected to me.

Comment: The workaround you suggest is what I'm currently doing, but I'd prefer not to have such quirks in the user interface.

Comment: @Wisperwind If you have for example `\foo[{\baz[...]}]` then there is one `<balanced text>` if we don't strip the braces, but at least three tokens otherwise. Depending on the subsequent processing, that might be important.